# How to align vertically and float to right in <div>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made this code:

```
<style>
.left-cell {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.right-cell {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:right;
}
</style>
<div class=""style="border: 3px dashed #ccc;width:290px;padding: 10px;">
<h4 style="text-align:center;">8$ taniej!</h4>
<div class="left-cell">
Skopiuj kupon: 
</div>
<div class="right-cell">
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-clipboard-text="CEBULAREDMI3PRO" class="kupony button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">CEBULAREDMI3PRO</button>
</div><br/>
<div class="left-cell">
Przedmiot: 
</div>
<div class="right-cell">
<a href="x.pl"><button class="button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro</button></a>
</div>
</div>
```

It looks that: [press here](http://screenshot.sh/mE6wnIcUvrB4p)
My question is how can I float buttons to right to get good-looking box?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle of that instead of a screenshot, or use the snippets option that would be more helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/09f8dzgb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the left-cell to `width:100%`and the buttons to `white-space:nowrap`

```css
.left-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.right-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}
.button {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="" style="border: 3px dashed #ccc;width:290px;padding: 10px;">
  <h4 style="text-align:center;">8$ taniej!</h4>
  <div class="left-cell">
    Skopiuj kupon:
  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
    <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-clipboard-text="CEBULAREDMI3PRO" class="kupony button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">CEBULAREDMI3PRO</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="left-cell">
    Przedmiot:
  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
    <a href="x.pl">
      <button class="button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but when i put this to bootstrap site it looks that: http://screenshot.sh/ouxJScuVk3lsd

Comment: I should point out that buttons in links is not best practice. If you want a link use one and style it like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give your parent div a `display:table`, and float your inner divs, repectively `float:left;` and `float:right;` .

This is a working snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.left-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
}
.right-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 3px dashed #ccc;width:290px;padding: 10px;">
  <h4 style="text-align:center;">8$ taniej!</h4>
  <div class="left-cell">
    Skopiuj kupon:
  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
    <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-clipboard-text="CEBULAREDMI3PRO" class="kupony button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">CEBULAREDMI3PRO</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="left-cell">
    Przedmiot:
  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
    <a href="x.pl">
      <button class="button" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xsb28myd/) Try with this css:

```
    .left-cell {
       display:table-cell;
       vertical-align:middle;
       float:left;
       width:40%;
    }
    .right-cell {
       display:table-cell;
       vertical-align:middle;
       text-align: right;
       width:60%;
    }
```